# Error on compiling jni directory using NDK r9d

Tags: android, compilation, android-ndk, mupdf

I am getting an error while compiling **jni** directory using NDK r9d

```
$ /cygdrive/c/Users/MEHDI/Downloads/Compressed/android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9d/ndk-build
Android NDK: WARNING:/cygdrive/e/android-sdk-windows/AndroidWorkspace/muPDF/jni/Android.mk:mupdfcore: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb : mupdf <= mupdf.c
E:/android-sdk-windows/AndroidWorkspace/muPDF/jni/mupdf.c:15:24: fatal error: mupdf/fitz.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/cygdrive/c/Users/MEHDI/Downloads/Compressed/android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/build-binary.mk:391: recipe for target '/cygdrive/e/android-sdk-windows/AndroidWorkspace/muPDF/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mupdf/mupdf.o' failed
make: *** [/cygdrive/e/android-sdk-windows/AndroidWorkspace/muPDF/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mupdf/mupdf.o] Error 1
```

Comment: It is said that you do not have the file:E:/android-sdk-windows/AndroidWorkspace/muPDF/jni/mupdf/fitz.h,check it first and then try again.

Comment: Did you put fitz.h file in jni folder?

Comment: yes inserted but now i am getting another error Android NDK: WARNING:/cygdrive/e/android-sdk-windows/AndroidWorkspace/muPDF/jni/Android.mk:mupdfcore: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries
[armeabi-v7a] Compile        : mupdf <= mupdf.c
/bin/sh: /cygdrive/c/Users/MEHDI/Downloads/Compressed/android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [/cygdrive/e/android-sdk-windows/AndroidWorkspace/muPDF/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mupdf/mupdf.o] Error 127

Comment: Plz help me out guys.....